# How can I maximize this functional, having a free boundary in it?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, optimization

$$\max \left\{-\int_B \left(\frac{d(\epsilon, x_i + \epsilon)}{\int_B C} \right) \log \left(\frac{d(\epsilon, x_i + \epsilon)}{\int_B C} \right)\right\}$$ where $B, C$ are boundary points and functional respectively, with some points in $B$ unknown and $C$ unknown, $d$ a metric on the points in $B$

Comment: What is the $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}$ doing in the denominator?

Comment: @user10354138, Thanks for that correction! I had entered the wrong expression!